# C++ constructor and destructor to set a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor, doubly-linked-list

The question is using the constructor to a set a node,
and using the destructor to make sure the prev and next make connected correctly.

```
  class ListNode {
    public:
        int data;
        ListNode *prev, *next;
        ListNode(int Data, ListNode* Prev, ListNode *Next);
        ~ListNode();
    };
```

This is my code

```
class ListNode {
public:
        int data;
        ListNode *prev, *next;
        ListNode(int Data, ListNode *Prev, ListNode *Next) {
            data = Data;
            prev = Prev;
            next = Next;
        }
        ~ListNode() {
            prev -> next = next;
            next -> prev = prev;
        }
};
```

I got a runtime error. How to fix this problem.
Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @d901203 The destructor may be defaulted because there is nothing to delete explicitly.

Comment: Can you rely on `prev` and `next` always pointing to a valid object, especially always being `!= nullptr`?

Comment: How should i to modify my code?

Comment: Not sure if it solves your problem (as you do not post the runtime error or any code to reproduce the error), but `if (prev) { prev->next = next; }` and `if(next)  {next->prev = prev;}` could help

Comment: @Stephan Lechner You are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor of a current node shall not touch data members of other nodes. And there is nothing in the class to delete explicitly. So the destructor shall be defaulted implicitly or explicitly as for example

```
~ListNode() = default;
```

It is the destructor of the list in whole (or for example a separate static function of the class `ListNode`) will bother to delete correctly all nodes in the list.

For example you could declare a list like

```
class List
{
private:
    ListNode
    {
        //...
    } *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;
    size_t size = 0;

public:
    ~List()
    {
        // delete all nodes in the list
    }
    //...
};
```

As for the constructor then it could be defined like

```
    explicit ListNode( int data, ListNode *prev = nullptr, ListNode *next = nullptr)
        : data( data ), prev( prev ), next( next ) 
    {
    }
```